# What is code screening?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I saw the term "code screening" in a job ad on the site — what does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This section is the [Joel test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/).

The verbose term for *Code screening* is *Do new candidates write code during their interview?*.

This means that during the interview, there will be some sort of code test, like the [Fizz Buzz test](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest)